# Build Turing Machine

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata, turing-machines

My question is how to build a Turing machine that is able to replace ab's in pairs with X, hence X will reflect the number of pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, no, the Turing-machine does not read or write symbols in pairs; it reads and writes exactly one symbol at a time.

Second, note that the strings to be accepted merely need to have as many $a$'s and $b$'s: the strings do not have to be of the form $(ab)^*$, but you should also accept a string like $aaabbb$ or $babbbaaa$. So when it says 'pairs' it does not mean that you have succesive $ab$'s on the input.

The general strategy is given in the hint in the question: for every $a$ that you find, also find a $b$, and replace both of them with $X$ ... and then keep repeating that.

The basic 'fork' or 'split' that you see, i.e the fact that from the starting node there are two possible nodes that you can transition to, reflects of course the fact that you can first run into an $a$, and thus will have to look for a $b$ later on the tape, *or* that you can first run into a $b$, and thus will look for an $a$ later.

So try that!

Comment: @Wills999 Closer, yes, but not quite there. So remeber that after you see an $a$ and replace it with an $X$, you should find a $b$ and replace that with an $X$. However, that $b$ may not be right next to the $a$. So, before you get to a $b$ (assuming there is one at all), you first need to skip any $a$'s ... that's what the loop is for. And of course same for when you first find a $b$. So, give it another shot!

Comment: @Wills999 Closer yet!  Please note that you can't read $XX$ and replace that with an $X$ like you try to do at $q_3$, so get rid of that transition. Instead, think of what brought you (at least initially) to state $q_3$: you just came from replacing a single $a$ and a single $b$ with an $X$, and now you are just to the right of that.  So, one thing to do at this point is just to go back to the beginning of the string and repeat the process. So: whatever symbol you are reading, go left ... until you see an empty cell, at which point you go right and now you're back at the beginning.  Try that!

Comment: @Wills999 The loop with $q_3$ is to go all the way back to the beginning of the string. So, whatever symbol you see, don;t replace it, but move left. So, the $A/A:L$ and $B/B:L$ are on the loop on $q_3$. And yes, you'll encvounter $X$'s as well, but need to pass those as well, so add $X/X:L$ that that loop.  But once you see the empty cell, you know you've gone beyond the left start of the string, so leave that cell alone, but move right, and now transition to $q_4$ .. which is basically the 'start of the loop' state.  That is, once back in $q_4$ start looking for a new $a$ or $b$.

Comment: @Wills999 OK, another improvement!  And I;m sorry, in the previous comment when I was referring to $q_4$ I meant $q_0$, but you did all that correctly: once it hits the empty cell to the left of the string, then keep it empty, move right, and go to $q_0$. OK, now, what you want to do when back in $q_0$, is to find a new $a$ or $b$ ... which means that you first have to skip all the $X$'s that you have replaced earlier $a$'s and $b$'s with. So: the loop will be $X/X:R$.  ... (continued)

Comment: @Wills999 However, what if you skip all those $X$'s and you reach an empty cell? That means you've reached the end of the string without finding another $a$ or $b$ ... and that means that there were just as many $a$'s as $b$'s! So, at that point you should stop and accept ... and that is what the transition to $q_4$ is for!  Indeed, $q_0$ is not a halting state, but $q_4$ is.

Comment: @Wills999 And one one more little thing: when from $q_1$ or $q_2$ you move to $q_3$, you really should start moving left already, rather than moving right.  This is because if you move right and you were at the end of the string, then after the move you're in state $q_3$ looking at an empty cell, but that was supposed to indicate that you are to the left of the string, rather than being on the right.

Comment: Thank you so much once again. for the loop on q0, I've made it X/X,R. Just a small question on this? if I do that will the machine still be able to compute 'empty string' as the input string? and when my everything is computed it will go to q4. Also I've made only q4 as a final state. Is everything correct? Ive updated the attempt.

Comment: @Wills999 One last fix: you have two transitions out of $q_0$ reading an $X$ ... that is not allowed for Turing machines, at least not determininstic ones. But the transition from $q_0$ to $q_4$ should not be X/X, but e/e (and move in any direction) .. and that will also take care of having the empty string as input: it will directly go to $q_4$ and halt.

Comment: @Wills999 Good!  ... don't forget the transition from $q_1$ to $q_3$ ...

Comment: Thank you once again. I have updated the answer. Just two questions, when you say 'move in any direction', how can I specify this? Can I write something like e/e : LR? Secondly, in the machine I have now my a's will return an X and my b's will also return an X but not when ab's in pairs with an X? To clarify it will be abab -> XXXX and not abab -> XX? is that a problem?

Comment: @Wills999 FIrst: no, you can't write LR ... but just pick one of L and R.  SEcond, yes, abab will be transformed into XXXX .... and then the machine will halt in $q_4$ ... which is good!

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your help. Just one last question, on Q1 and Q2 do I need to skip Xs. For example, if I have an input string such as aaabbb, in around the 2nd iterate I will be Xs that need to jumped over. is this necessary? Thank you very much for your continuous help! really do appreciate it.

Comment: @Wills999 Yes, that's right, good catch! See, you're getting it! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate your help! Cheers!!

Comment: @Wills999 No problem!  Since you're new: If you feel satisfied with the answer, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark next to my answer.